# Read huge data from Mongo db and exporting it to the excel

Tags: java, excel, mongodb, spring-boot

I have a requirement where I need to read the huge data from Mongo db collection and based on some conditions populate it to the excel sheet so that end user can download and see the data (Approx. ~ 1.5 million).

Currently I am using mongoTemplate to access the collection and using pipeline to filter out the data. Something like-

```
List<Document> aggResponse = paReportingCollection.aggregate(pipeline).into(new ArrayList<>());
```

I need a way to write the data into excel without crashing the system.

P.S. I have gone through few pagination blogs but doesn't seem a good option.

Comment: "Approx. ~ 15 lacs" - note that not everyone might know what a "lac" is, better transform it into an international format.

Comment: If you get more data than a single excel file can contain (e.g. restricted by the number of rows) then you need to split it or use another format. If you need to use excel then one option might be to return a zip file with multiple excel files that each contain a portion of the data.

Comment: @Thomas thanks for pointing it out, I did change into an international format.

Coming to your suggestion - Is there any other option like streams/batch which can do the work instead of creating multiple excels and send it as zip because it will deviate from the client requirement.

Comment: An excel file can only hold about [1 million rows] (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3) so there's no sense in even trying to stream. If you have less rows and only memory is a problem then have a look at the streaming approaches [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/) provides.

Comment: Also don't transform your entire result set into an array in memory. Open and iterate through your cursor to append entries to the sheet one at a time if the Excel API allows for it